# OpenSSH-Server: How can I remotely set the client's side window title?

Tags: openssh

I have an OpenSSH server running under Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  I'm connecting to it from a Windows 7 machine via [PuTTY's SSH client](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). I have found this option on Putty client named `Disable remote-controlled window title changing`:

[image: Disable remote-controlled window title changing]

... that, basically, allows the SSH Server to change the Putty's **window title**. But I have found no docs about how can OpenSSH-Server at the Linux side be configured to **send such window title change** order.

If that info is on [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5) I have not found it.

I have only found methods for changing this window title **at the client** (they must be run at the client side), but this is not what I am searching for (due to I use different SSH clients, not only Putty). For example, the Putty method is at *Windows --> Behaviour --> Window title*:

[image]

#### Additional points

1. In order to make things clearer, let's suppose some scenario where we only have **control of the SSH Server machine**, and we can **not** modify/access/configure anything **on the SSH client**.
2. The way to solve this `Send title change order` for [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) (Windows version) is [here](https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicView&sTicket=21637_f96knerb). I don't think it will be useful for OpenSSH Server as long as it is a Linux program, but... who knows? Anyway, it is a good working example of the **case scenario** referred to on the above *point 1*: the only **change is made on the server** side, and the title window on the remote connecting (via SSH) computer gets automatically changed

Answer (score 2):

It's a shell feature, not a feature of sshd. You need to make the shell running on the SSH server send a title change control sequence. See [How to change the title of an xterm](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html) for explanations.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez & cuonglm: Actually, this does answer the question, albeit tersely. Sending the order *is* a shell feature (interpreting the order is a feature of PuTTY).